# Zendesk PHP API searching for user by email returns full list of all users

Tags: zendesk

Using the Zendesk PHP API (github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php) to search for a user by email returns a full list of all users, instead of just matching results.

```
$user = $zendesk->users()->search(array('email'=>'mail@mail.com'));
```

The goal is to fetch a specific user by email, get that users ID and later search for tickets related to a specific user.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The search query key does not support specific field names, the key has to be 'query'.
So it should look like this instead:

```
$user = $zendesk->users()->search(array('query'=>'mail@mail.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using curl then here is the example call

```
$this->curlWrap("/search.json?query=type:user+email:$user_email", $json, "GET");
```

For more details you can visit this tutorial: [Zendesk API Implementation In Codeigniter](http://foreachphp.com/zendesk-api-implementation-in-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

The `search` method accepts `external_id` & `query` only.
So, if you need to use Zendesk PHP API, you can search like this:

```
$user = $zendesk->users()->search(array('query'=>'type:user+email:mail@mail.com'));
```